# grpc-java - java_plugin not found

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to get a program running. I installed grpc-java in one of my folders on linux. I did ../gradlew publishToMavenLocal for grpc-java and it was successful but I don't find anything generated in /usr/local. How to resolve the compile error below and make sure java-plugin is found? Any pointers? I am new to linux.

- compiling route
  /usr/local/grpc/java-plugin-1.15.0/exe/java_plugin/protoc-gen-grpc-java: program not found or is not executable
  --grpc-java_out: protoc-gen-grpc-java: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Comment: I was able to change and compile it. Had to change grpc-home variable.

Answer (score 1):

grpc is not executable binary (it is a library). anyways, the output of publishToMavenLocal should be in `~/.m2/` directory if you haven't override default. 
if you want to compile grpc, please read [COMPILING.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/COMPILING.md).

i recommend to follow https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/java/